# Entity loads the same data set for each dynamic page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using an entity data source to load data to a listview on page y, based on AuctionId Request.QueryString parameter provided from the page x. The strange problem is, that despite the fact that QueryString provides correct id, page y is loaded properly only for the first item clicked from page x, all next are loaded with the data from 2nd item on page x.

Here is my where statement:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            AuctionEntity.WhereParameters.Add(new Parameter("auctionid", TypeCode.Int32, Request.QueryString["AuctionId"]));
            AuctionEntity.Where = "it.[Id] = @auctionid";



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the problem was that if the 2nd value i provided via the QueryString  (not id that i used in where parameter) was the same, it made entity work as i desribed.